# ngx-ssrs-reportviwer throws TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement':

Tags: angular, reporting-services

I am trying to use the ngx-ssrs-reportviewer in an angular 7.2.15 project, I just followed the instructions on the npm js site https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer but anytime I load the page I get an error

elements.js:384 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
    at NgElementImpl.NgElement [as constructor] (elements.js:384)
    at new NgElementImpl (elements.js:420)
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.createElement (platform-browser.js:1055)

I am not sure to go with this - there are lots of errors regarding failing to construct an HTMLElement however none seem to point me in the right the direction not sure what to look at at this point so hopefully someone can help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by downgrading to ssrs-reportviewer 2.0.5